# Jquery css("top") returns "undefined"

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to set the property of a DIV element using the .css(...) method of Jquery, but it keeps returning "undefined" both before and after I set the value.  Here is the code snippet:

```
var isense =
{
    $dialog: $('#isense'),
    $box: null, // gets set before call to ShowDialog

    ...

    ShowDialog: function (data)
            {
                var height = this.$box.height() + 9;
                var $offset = this.$box.offset();
                var content = $('<div />').append($('#isensetemplate').tmpl(data)).html();

                $('.isenseperson').remove();
                this.$dialog.append(content);               
                this.$dialog.css("left", $offset.left);
                this.$dialog.css("top", $offset.top + height);      

                this.$dialog.show();
            },
    ...
}
```

I've stepped through in the IE9 debugger (my code has to run in IE), and **this.$box** is an object (jquery object) wrapping the element I am trying to show the DIV at.  The **$offset** has the right numbers (they are positive and look to be the right location).

The problem is, after I call **this.$dialog.css("left", $offset.left)**, the value of **this.$dialog.css("left")** is "undefined".  It's "undefined" both before and after the call.  The same for "top".  Then the call to **this.$dialog.show()** doesn't seem to do anything, that is, I don't see the dialog (the style property for that dialog is initially set to include "display: none;").

Also, the content variable does hold some HTML, and it looks right, so I don't think that's the issue.  Any ideas?  I've seen the css properties return "undefined" before and I couldn't figure out why.

I am using **Jquery 1.4.4**, and the code is running inside a webbrowser control in .NET which is **IE7**.  I ran it in IE9 and it too has the same issue.

UPDATE: I just tried with the latest **Jquery 1.5.2** and it still has the same problem.

Comment: When do you run the code? Does the element with `id="isense"` exist before `var isense = { ... }` is executed?

Comment: You sure `this.*` holds what you think it does? How are you calling `ShowDialog`? Try `isense.ShowDialog.call(isense, data);` instead of whatever you're doing, otherwise `this` will just point to the global `window` object.

Comment: @davin: Then the parameter `data` will contain `isense`, and the value of `data` is ignored...

Comment: @Guffa, huh? What I wrote would provide context for `this` and the parameter `data` would hold the argument `data` sent through...

Comment: what happens if you show it then move it?

Comment: @Davin: Sorry, missed the `.call` part... Anyway, that wouldn't change anything from using `isense.ShowDialog(data);`.

Comment: @Guffa, indeed! Wow, didn't know I was given object scope for free...

Comment: I appreciate the comments.  I think the first comment was close to the mark.  I noticed that my var isense = {...} code was in between two <script> tags in the head, but not inside the jquery document ready function.  Although at the time ShowDialog is called, this.$dialog looked like a legit jquery object wrapper to the isense DIV, it apparently wasn't.  I added this.$dialog = $('#isense') to the top of ShowDialog and everything worked fine.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the variable $dialog is actually pointing to something. Maybe:

```
if ($dialog.length == 0) {
    alert('$dialog variable is empty!')
}
```

And just for the hell of it, try it in a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

The element has to exist before you can find it. Make sure that the object is created after the document has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var isense = {
    ...
  }

});
```

Comment: This was in fact the problem.  I didn't have my code in the document ready function, so I think it was wrapping the isense DIV tag prior to fully initializing or something.  Rather than moving the var isense = {}, I added this.$dialog = $('#isense'); to the top of ShowDialog.

Thanks for the help.